# Update issue in JIRA when card is moved in Trello using Zapier

Tags: jira, zapier, trello

We are using Zapier to sync tickets from consulting clients' boards to our internal one for recordkeeping and tracking. We've got the basics working, like comments being added and new tickets being created, but I'm struggling with how to get Zapier to track when a card is moved in Trello and update its status in JIRA (software cloud version). Any suggestions/help?

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

This is technically possible (I did a similar setup to track my own tasks), but it's complex and fragile.

To make the write to jira, you'll call the [transitions](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/#api-rest-api-3-issue-issueIdOrKey-transitions-post) endpoint. Each issue, based on its position on the board, has a number of transitions available to it. Imagine a 3-column setup of todo, doing, and done. Both the trello and jira boards have these columns.

You'll need a zap for each transition (2, in this case). They're each very similar.

1. Trigger: Card Moved to List (Trello, specify "doing" column)
2. Filter (ensure `listBefore.name == "todo"`)
3. Action: Transition Issue (you'll need a custom jira app here, more on that below)

With that running, every time you move a card from `todo` -> `doing`, Zapier will make an API call to move the matching jira issue in the same fashion. Make sure your trello cards have the jira key in their title.

---

Re: the custom app for step 3. You'll want to use the [developer platform](https://platform.zapier.com). You can use our [blueprint](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform/tree/master/example-apps/create) to make an app with a single "create" step. The tricky part is that you'll have to store the id of the jira transform in that app. For instance, `todo -> doing` might be ID 1, while `doing -> done` is ID 2. Those can be found via the API ([info](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/#api-rest-api-3-issue-issueIdOrKey-transitions-get)).

You'll be able to know which transform you should be doing and call the correct on here.

---

Like I mentioned, this is a pretty complex process. Though Zapier can totally get the job done, if anyone ever changes your jira board setup, the transformation ids will change and your flow will break. Instead, I'd recommend checking out something in the marketplace (such as [this](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1215077/trello-sync-for-jira?hosting=server&tab=overview), the result of a random google). Something like that will hopefully be more robust.